# Select XML values when attribute involved

Tags: sql-server-2008, xml

I have a table that stores XML values in field: OtherData.

An XML value from one row:

```
< file path="C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe" />
```

I would like to select all rows that have an attribute path like '%svchost%'

What is the right SQL query to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used an XQUERY approach but different from yours (@Allen White):

```
Select * From Table where OtherData.value('(/file/@path)[1]', 'varchar (1000)') LIKE '%svchost.exe%'
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the XQuery CONTAINS method, like this:

```
SELECT CASE @x.exist
(
N'/bikes/Product[1]/Specifications[contains(., "Novice")]'
)
WHEN 1 THEN N'The bike is good for novices'
WHEN 0 THEN N'The bike is for more advanced riders'
END;
```

Good luck.

Comment: Can you add a reference to where you copy/pasted that please? Not least for more information